# TypeError in leaflet on zoom in or out

Tags: leaflet

I am working on an application that renders land parcels from PostGIS as polygons in Leaflet.
I have an event handler set for 'viewreset' on the map:

```
this.leaflet_map.on('viewreset', this.viewport.regenerate, this.viewport);
```

The `this` in this case is an object I've created, called `pt_map`. `viewport` is an object I've created to wrap the methods for regenerating the view based on the current map bounds. My code works on initial load, as well as on panning the map. However, when I zoom in or out, I get the following error in line 4842 of leaflet-src.js:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'latLngToLayerPoint' of null

Any ideas? My full code is available at https://github.com/CoherentLogic/ptarmigan/blob/experimental/web/ptarmigan/parcels/layers.js

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the function you call in a closure

`this.leaflet_map.on('viewreset', function(e){this.viewport.regenerate(e)}, this);`

it's vastly more complex than what I'm about to say but as a general rule of thumb it's a bad idea to use a function with a dot in it as an argument to something else without using a closure.

Comment: check the scope of this inside of the anonymous function. It may not mean what you think it means.

Comment: my bad especially as my answer was telling him not to do that, fixed the typo.